# Horizontal Alignment of two div when the screen is smallest

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have to arrange two `divs` in horizontally, in large medium and small it is working fine but when I go to `xs` it don't works.

the code is following

```
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-2" id="Leftlist">
      <ul>
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>DEFG</li>
        <li>HIJ</li>
        <li>KLM</li>
        <li>NOP</li>
        <li>QRST</li>
        <li>UVW</li>
        <li>XYZ</li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-10" id="RightPara">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**For large small and medium code works perfectly**
[image]

**But for extra small window it dont works**
[image]

Can someone please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col-xs-` has been dropped in Bootstrap 4 in favor of `col-`.

Replace `col-xs-2 and col-xs-10` with `col-10 and col-2` and let me know if it works. :)

Comment: How can I increase the width of the largest so that it fits the big screens. At the moment everything is just in the center of my screen

Comment: I dont really know your code, but this is probably because you are using .container-fluid (which has a witdth of 100% but still has right and left padding that you gotta overwrite) and .container(which is always equal to 80% of the current screen width, so you would have to see it to 100%). My suggestion is that you overwrite all padding and margins, and give width : 100% !important to all of their parents, and see how they behave. :)